# RavenDB on IIS/Windows 10

Tags: ravendb, windows-10

I've been trying to RavenDB 3.0 on IIS on Windows 10 using the installer but it declined the installation due to the IIS version. How can I install it manaully

Answer (score 2):

Just download the zip file and manually copy the files to your chosen IIS directory.

The latest version is here:
http://hibernatingrhinos.com/downloads/RavenDB/3690

And you can follow these instructions for step by step installation in IIS:
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/installation/IIS